# Is it 'ok' to ask questions about tv series which are in middle of the season?

Tags: discussion

I wanna ask a question about *[Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series))*, but it is currently in its 5th episode of season 1. They currently release an episode each week.

Is it 'ok'/'recommended' to ask questions about the series even though all episodes are not out yet? Or should I wait 'till the end of the season to ask my questions?

I'm asking this because maybe they can release explanations for my questions in future episodes, so I don't know if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### It depends

If you're asking about issues **already** covered then it's fine.

On the other hand asking for **speculation** then that's a different matter.

Honestly, questions about motives, possible backstory etc. are best left to the end of a season *unless* that information has already been shown as those questions will tend to generate opinion-based responses.

As I said, it depends what it is you are asking about.

Comment: SF/F has a policy that actively polices such speculative predict-the-future questions; are you suggesting a similar policy here? Should such questions be closed, downvoted, edited, etc, or should we just continue to recommend to askers to wait?

Comment: *If you're asking about issues already covered then it's fine.* The problem with such a demarcation is that things often end up changing later through the season, even when they appear to have been resolved. It's not always a concrete line that can be drawn.

Comment: I'm not suggesting any *policy* just giving my interpretation of existing policy. Each question should be judged independently. I agree that "predict the future" questions are bad...but "why did that happen" *based on what we've seen* are probably OK. But until the question is asked...we don't know.

Comment: We actually generally allow questions that may not be answerable *yet* as long as they aren't asking people to speculate what might happen. It doesn't only have to be covered already. I agree with the speculation point.

Comment: SF&F's policy is also a little messed up with the whole reopening *once* it becomes (supposedly) answerable (and usually trivially so) thing.